# Is that possible to get customer attribute in custom grid?

Tags: customer-attribute

Here i m create one customer attribute.

Using custom module i want to change customer attribute.

Now i want that customer attribute column in my custom grid

in my custom table i m saving customer id.

So is it possible?

[image]
I want this attribute in my custom module grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is work for me

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("module/model")->getCollection();
        $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('customer', '[your attribute name]');
        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('l' => 'customer_entity_int'),
                'main_table.customer_ids = l.entity_id');
        $collection->getSelect()->where('l.attribute_id =?',$attributeId);
        $collection->load();
```